# How to display condition message on below of password text field in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, password-protection

I want to display a password condition which should be shown when I enter the password and condition.

It should be shown below the text field of the password.

I need to know how I can do that I have a screen shot of this password textfield and message below of this text field.

[image: here i want to display like this]

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: you need to use vuejs or jquery for that, google it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue.js and axios to validate and display the errors. Have a route called /validate-data in a controller to validate the data.

app.js file:

```
       import Vue           from 'vue'
        window.Vue = require('vue');
        window.axios = require('axios');

        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

        let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

        if (token) {
            window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
        } else {
            console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
        }

             class Errors {
                constructor() {
                    this.errors = {};
                }

                get(field) {
                    if (this.errors[field]) {

                        return this.errors[field][0];
                    }
                }

                record(errors) {
                    this.errors = errors;
                }

                clear(field) {
                    delete this.errors[field];
                }

                has(field) {
                    return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
                }

                any() {
                    return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
                }
            }

            new Vue({
             el: '#app',

                data:{
               errors: new Errors(),
              model: {
    business-name: '',
    business-description: '',
    business-phone: ''
    },
            },

        methods: {
          onComplete: function(){
              axios.post('/validate-data', this.$data.model)
                  // .then(this.onSuccess)
                  .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
           },
}
        });
```

Make a route called /validate-data with a method in the controller, do a standard validate

```
$this->validate(request(), [
 'business-name'=> 'required|string|max:255',
    'business-description'=> 'required|string',
    'business-phone' => 'nullable|phone|numeric',
    'business-email' => 'nullable|email',
    'business-street'=> 'required|string',
    'business-city' => 'required|string',
    'business-state' => 'required|string|max:2',
    'business-zip' => 'required|min:5|max:5|numeric'
]
```

);

Then create your inputs in your view file, using v-model that corresponds to the vue.js data model fields. Underneath it, add a span with an error class (basic red error styling, for example) that only shows up if the errors exist. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="business-name" v-model="model.business-name" class="input">
<span class="error-text" v-if="errors.has('business-name')" v-text="errors.get('business-name')"></span>
```

Don't forget to include the app.js file in footer of your view file. Remember to include the  tag, and run npm run watch to compile the vue code. This will allow you to validate all errors underneath their input fields.

Forgot to add, have a buttton that has @onclick="onComplete" to run the validate method.

Comment: Hi my front end is in jquery/javascript can you please show me in this